# Pinescript Alert every month after trade executed

Tags: pine-script

`

```
tarttime = input.time(title = "starttime", defval = timestamp("31 October 2022 00:00 +0000"))
```

`

If my entry for trade as per input date selection, then after each 1 month or 4 weeks later gives alerts that completed 1 month.

pls advise, how this possible?

Required alert on weekly candle.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is you condition to enter a trade, but if you want to send an alert 4 weeks after a long condition and you are on weekly candle, you can just check for it using history reference `[ ]`:

```
if long_condition[4]
    alert("Long 4 weeks ago")
```

Comment: yes, this could be best solution. many thanks